# UWP RSACryptoServiceProvider equivalent code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, cryptography, uwp, rsa

I'm porting WP8.1 Silverlight to UWP. My WP8.1 Code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var key = Resources.key;
rsa.FromXmlString(key);
```

I used the provider to load the key from xml and to en-/decode.
In UWP this class is not available. So how exactly does it work now? I tried with RSA class and CryptographicEngine, but i cant get it working. How to load my xml key there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have read this article [RSA cryptography between a WinRT and a .Net app](http://www.japf.fr/2013/05/rsa-cryptography-between-a-winrt-and-a-dotnet-app/)

> For each platform, you have the creation of the key pair, the encryption and the description method.

Comment: Thanks for the Link and the Answer! One more thing: How can I Import my existing key pair from xml file?

Comment: check this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461380/uwp-universal-windows-platform-rsa-asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider-import-publi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461380/uwp-universal-windows-platform-rsa-asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider-import-publi)

Comment: Thanks. But I dont see any help there. I have two xml files. One public, and one private key. And I need to import them now. Not possible with this code... :(

Comment: You could [load xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202911/how-to-parse-xml-data-using-c-sharp-via-an-uwp-application) and get attribute's value in uwp.

Comment: How can I put attributes values to AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider?

Comment: This was not the Answer! I can not use my own Keys. Do I always have to generate new keys? I dont want that!!